# Proof that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/I \cong \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Can someone help me with this problem?

> Consider the ideal $I = \lbrace{a+bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i] : 5\vert{a}\text{ and }5\vert{b}}\rbrace.$ Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/I \cong \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: By the first isomorphism theorem, it is enough to construct a homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\left[i\right]\to\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ which is onto and $\ker f=I$. Can you think of such a homomorphism?

Comment: And to add to Guy's hint, a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[i] \to A$ is equivalent to a choice of element $x \in A$ (the image of $i$) such that $x^2 = -1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $\phi : \mathbb{Z}[i] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} $ be given by $\phi (z)=(Re (z) (\mod 5), Im(z)(\mod 5)) $ .

Take $(m, n)\in \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} $ . So $z=(5s+m)+i(5t+n)$ is mapped via $\phi $ to $(m,n)$ . 
So  the map is onto and $I=ker \phi $ .

Now use first isomorphism theorem for rings

Comment: I had no idea that $(0,1)^2 = (-1,-1)$

Comment: That $\phi$ is not a ring homomorphism.